# Javascript strange Pass-by-X activity

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two similar codes that either passes-by-reference and value depending on different circumstance shown below:

**Sample 1**

```js
var numbers = [1,2,3];
function popper(){
 var popped = numbers.pop();
 return popped;
}
console.log(numbers,popper());
```

**Sample 2**

```js
function numbers(){
 var arry = [1,2,3];
 return arry;
}
function popper(){
 var popped = numbers().pop();
 return popped;
}

console.log(numbers(),popper());
```

I read that only primitives are passed-by-value and others are passed by reference. However, in **Sample 1**, numbers array is passed-by-value while in **Sample 2**, the numbers() function containing same array is passed-by-reference. Any description of what's happening internally would be great.

*Bonus Question*: Any way to look at the Array prototype of numbers in both samples?

Comment: why do you say that in sample 1 array is passed by value?

Comment: the original array size changed after applying pop() method on it in sample 1. that's my guess

Comment: yes, it changed because array was passed by reference

Comment: but shouln't javascript create a reference to the numbers array in sample 1 like it did in sample 2?

Comment: In sample 1, you are using same object to pop, but in sample 2 you are using different object. When you call numbers function it always create you new object

Comment: @karman you're 100% right.thanks!!! so is there any way in sample 2, to echo the effects of pop(), on the array located inside the function numbers()?

Comment: @Jamie You need to give the reference of array, either you can declare it globally(sample 1) or pass the same object to function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample 1

you have create a global variable number

```
var numbers = [1,2,3];
```

The function popper is using that variable to pop a value.

Now in console.log you have passed two arguments: numbers and a function call

In order for console.log to print out the result, the function passed will first be evaluated,
 i.e the global numbers variable will be now  [1,2] with return value of popper as 3

Hence the output is

[1, 2] 3

Sample 2

You have create a function numbers with returns an array of numbers

Note: every time you call the function numbers, a new array is returned.

There is also a popper method which does not use any global variable numbers as before but calls the number function which returns a new array of numbers.

Now in console.log you have passed two function calls

Again as explained above, the functions will first be evaluated before console.log prints the outputs.

So,

calling numbers() with give a new array [1,2,3]

and

calling popper() with give 3, since a new array will be used i.e [1,2,3] and popped value will be 3

Hence the output will be

[1,2,3] 3

Comment: thanks a lot!! nice, elegant and detailed explanation friend!!

Answer (score 1):

This is actually logically consistent. JavaScript will always pass arrays by reference. In the Sample 2, you actually create a new array when you call `numbers()` inside the `console.log(...` again.

In addition, you aren't actually passing the variables, but just using the scope. To actually pass the array, you would need to do something like this:

```
var numbers = [1,2,3];
function popper(nums2){
    var popped = nums2.pop();
    return popped;
}
console.log(numbers,popper(numbers));
```

Step by step:

**Sample 1**

1. Define `numbers`
2. Call `popper()` which will modify `numbers`
3. Log to console

**Sample 2**

1. Call `popper()`
2. Call `numbers()` in `popper()` which returns an array
3. `popper()` modifies the array from above
4. Call `numbers()` in the `console.log(...` line again
5. `numbers()` now creates a new array and returns that to `console.log(`

Comment: yes, in sample 2 a new instance of the array was created so the original remained unaffected. however i can't get why in sample 1 javascript didn't create a new reference to the array numbers (whose value changed after applying pop() method)

Comment: @sinisake holy sheet you're right..been scratching my head since morning on such stupid mistake :D thanks!!

Comment: @sinisake haha half true tbf. the part where executing function before variable sure changes the value of variable, which is correct :)